# Do the correct inputrc command by a shell line code

Tags: bash, readline, rc

How do we do inputrc command by a shell line code as gave failure here

```
$ bind -x '"\C-l":next-history'

bash: next-history: command not found  
$
```

Please do sincere help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `man bash`:

> - -x *keyseq*:*shell-command*
>
>   Cause  *shell-command*  to be executed whenever *keyseq* is entered. [...]

So for your case when you press <kbd>CTRL-L</kbd>, Bash will try to execute a command named `next-history`.

To map to Readline's `next-history` you can write like this:

```
bind '"\C-l": next-history'
```